# Any download command is terminated with this error - "Errors were encountered while processing: linux-image-4.15.0-20-generic"

Tags: 18.04, grub2

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  android-libext4-utils android-libselinux android-libsepol libf2fs0
Use 'sudo apt autoremove' to remove them.
The following additional packages will be installed:
  libappindicator1 libglade2-0 libindicator7
Suggested packages:
  indicator-application
The following packages will be REMOVED:
  linux-image-4.15.0-20-generic
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  libappindicator1 libglade2-0 libindicator7 linuxdcpp
0 upgraded, 4 newly installed, 1 to remove and 255 not upgraded.
6 not fully installed or removed.
Need to get 1,055 kB of archives.
After this operation, 3,730 kB disk space will be freed.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
Get:1 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic/universe amd64 libindicator7 amd64 16.10.0+18.04.20180321.1-0ubuntu1 [21.7 kB]
Get:2 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic/universe amd64 libappindicator1 amd64 12.10.1+18.04.20180322.1-0ubuntu1 [19.4 kB]
Get:3 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic/universe amd64 libglade2-0 amd64 1:2.6.4-2 [44.6 kB]
Get:4 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic/universe amd64 linuxdcpp amd64 1.1.0-4 [969 kB]
Fetched 1,055 kB in 1s (1,325 kB/s)
(Reading database ... 170760 files and directories currently installed.)
Removing linux-image-4.15.0-20-generic (4.15.0-20.21) ...
/etc/kernel/postrm.d/initramfs-tools:
update-initramfs: Deleting /boot/initrd.img-4.15.0-20-generic
/etc/kernel/postrm.d/zz-update-grub:
Sourcing file `/etc/default/grub'
/usr/sbin/grub-mkconfig: 1: /etc/default/grub: If: not found
run-parts: /etc/kernel/postrm.d/zz-update-grub exited with return code 127
dpkg: error processing package linux-image-4.15.0-20-generic (--remove):
 installed linux-image-4.15.0-20-generic package post-removal script subprocess returned error exit status 1
Errors were encountered while processing:
 linux-image-4.15.0-20-generic
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

After running `cat /etc/default/grub`:

```
If you change this file, run 'update-grub' afterwards to update
# /boot/grub/grub.cfg.
# For full documentation of the options in this file, see:
#   info -f grub -n 'Simple configuration'

GRUB_DEFAULT=0
#GRUB_HIDDEN_TIMEOUT=0
GRUB_HIDDEN_TIMEOUT_QUIET=true
GRUB_TIMEOUT=10
GRUB_DISTRIBUTOR=`lsb_release -i -s 2> /dev/null || echo Debian`
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash nomodeset acpi_oci=\"Linux\""
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX=""

# Uncomment to enable BadRAM filtering, modify to suit your needs
# This works with Linux (no patch required) and with any kernel that obtains
# the memory map information from GRUB (GNU Mach, kernel of FreeBSD ...)
#GRUB_BADRAM="0x01234567,0xfefefefe,0x89abcdef,0xefefefef"

# Uncomment to disable graphical terminal (grub-pc only)
#GRUB_TERMINAL=console

# The resolution used on graphical terminal
# note that you can use only modes which your graphic card supports via VBE
# you can see them in real GRUB with the command `vbeinfo'
#GRUB_GFXMODE=640x480

# Uncomment if you don't want GRUB to pass "root=UUID=xxx" parameter to Linux
#GRUB_DISABLE_LINUX_UUID=true

# Uncomment to disable generation of recovery mode menu entries
#GRUB_DISABLE_RECOVERY="true"

# Uncomment to get a beep at grub start
#GRUB_INIT_TUNE="480 440 1"
```

Comment: Please `cat /etc/default/grub`  Expand your question for output.